# Set picture as wallpaper but allowing user to resize it

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bitmap, wallpaper

What I want to do is set a wallpaper from a bitmap, so my code right now looks like this:

```
WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
wm.setBitmap(myBitmap);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wallpaper set!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And this is working fine, but what I want is the app to start an intent and ask the user the size of the picture he wants to set, just like it does when you want to set a wallpaper from the gallery. Like this:

[image: wallpaper size chooser]

How can I do that?